# Ajax call returning null model when using form inside data table?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have a bootstrap form inside data-table and i am updating one input filed in this form actually there are multiple input fields and when I press submit button if any new data is entered in fields it will be updated in the database I am using ajax call for sending the data but as we know there are multiple pages in data-table so at the first page data is submitted successfully but on the other pages ajax call sending null model to the controller which cause null data exception.

```
<form id="share">
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
<div class="container col-md-12">
    <table id="myTable" class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered dataTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align:center">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => Model.tags.First().Id)</th>
                <th style="text-align:center">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => Model.tags.First().TagName)</th>
                <th style="text-align:center">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => Model.tags.First().TagCategory)</th>
                <th style="text-align:center">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => Model.tags.First().TagValue)</th>
                <th style="text-align:center"> Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.tags.Count(); i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.tags[i].Id)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.tags[i].Id)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.tags[i].TagName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.tags[i].TagCategory)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.tags[i].TagValue, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "TagVaule_" + Model.tags[i].Id, @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.tags[i].TagValue, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
                        {
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="UpdateRow(@Model.tags[i].Id)">Update</button>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="UpdateRow(@Model.tags[i].Id)" disabled>Update</button>

                        }
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content" id="myModalContent">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-5 col-md-10">
            @if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
            {
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="bulkupdate">BulkUpdate</button>
            }
            else
            {
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="bulkupdate" disabled>BulkUpdate</button>

            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
@section Scripts{

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#myTable').DataTable({
                'columns': [
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    { "width": "20%" },
                    null
                ],


            });
        });

        var form = $("#share");
        $(document).on('click', '#bulkupdate',function () {
            debugger;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '@Url.Action("BulkUpdate", "Home")',
                data: form.serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#myModalContent').html(data);
                    $('#myModal').modal('show');
                }
            });

        });
        //BulkUpdate Confirmation
         function BulkConfirm()
         {
             var form= $("#share");
                $.ajax({
                   type: 'POST', //GET
                   url: '@Url.Action("BulkUpdateConfirmation", "Home")',
                   data: form.serialize()
                });
                $("#myModal").modal('hide')
            }

        //Single row update
        var RowId = 0;
        var tagvalue = 0;
            function UpdateRow(id)
            {

                tagvalue = $("#TagVaule_" + id).val();
                RowId = id;
                DisplayModal();
                 }

            function DisplayModal()
            {

                 $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                     url: '@Url.Action("Update","Home")',
                    data: {
                        id: RowId,
                        value: tagvalue
                    },
                    success: function(data)
                {
                    $('#myModalContent').html(data);
                    $('#myModal').modal('show');
                     },

                });

            }
            function Confirm()
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("SaveUpdate","Home")',
                    data: {
                        id: RowId,
                        value: tagvalue
                    },
                });
                $("#myModal").modal('hide')
            }

    </script>
}

//Controller Code
    public ActionResult BulkUpdate(List<Tag> tags)
        {
            foreach (var item in tags)
            {
                if (item.TagValue == null || Regex.Matches(item.TagValue.ToString(), @"[a-zA-Z]").Count > 0)
                {
                    return PartialView("_InvalidModel");
                }
            }
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                obj.updatedDatas = new List<UpdatedData>();
                foreach (var item in tags)
                {
                    var tag = db.Tags.Where(x => x.Id.Equals(item.Id)).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (tag.TagValue != item.TagValue)
                    {

                        UpdatedData changedRow = new UpdatedData
                        {
                            OldTagValue = tag.TagValue,
                            NewTagValue = item.TagValue,
                            TagName = tag.TagName
                        };
                        obj.updatedDatas.Add(changedRow);
                    }
                }

            }
            return PartialView("_UpdateConfirmationBulk", obj);
        }
```

I am updating the form in two ways one is single row update and the other is multiple row updates or bulk update I am facing this issue in bulk update as in bulk update user changes the values of as many inputs as he want (also from other pages) and press the bulk update button to submit all the changes at a time.

Comment: Show code written in controller action for bulk upload and the model class

Comment: Also on click you are calling BulkUpload() but I do not see the function in your script

Comment: Rajesh G I updated the code

Comment: Did you debug the AJAX call? Also did you check the data post in Ajax call in network tab of developer tool?

Comment: Rajesh G this link is the solution but not working for me    https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-how-to-submit-all-pages-form-data/